# Python selenium - how can I loop a function to make 100 Copy accounts using different emails

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

How can I loop a different string into the email field, or a variable without actually having to make a list that consist of 100 different emails. For example is there a way i can send *money@qa.test* to the email field then *money1@qa.test* and so on.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest
class CreateAccount(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        global driver
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get("http://www.copy.com")
        driver.maximize_window()

def test_main(self):
    createNewAccount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[5]/div[1]/a")
    createNewAccount.click()

    firstName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dom_id_3']")
    lastName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dom_id_4']")
    emailField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dom_id_5']")
    passwordField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dom_id_6']")

    submitButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/form/button")

    firstName.send_keys("mike")
    lastName.send_keys("mano")
    emailField.send_keys("money@qa.test")
    passwordField.send_keys("test12")

    submitButton.click()

    try:
       xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/article[2]/div[4]/header/div[2]/div/div[4]/a")
       print("Yeah")

    except NoSuchElementException:
       print("Failed")
       raise Exception(NoSuchElementException)


def tearDown(self):
   driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

Comment: Do you know the email addresses in advance, i.e. are you working from a fixed list? Or could you make up the email addresses in the code?

Comment: I am needing the same thing. I would like my test case to generate a new email id every time it runs. for example, xyz@abc.com, then the next time when it runs it should generate xyz1@abc.com, xyz2@abc.com and so on and so forth.
Below is my code:
int i = 0; for(int count=1; count < 2; i++){ driver.findElement(By.name("signupDialogEmail")).sendKeys("mholmgren" + i + "@gmail.com");
The above code keeps looping and keeps generating ids after ids.

Comment: Mike, is that intended to be an answer to the question,  or are you saying, "Me too!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to register 100 accounts, this is a simple addition to your code to do that.

```
for i in range(100):
    email_address = "money" + str(i) + "@qa.test"
    firstName.send_keys("mike")
    lastName.send_keys("mano")
    emailField.send_keys(email_address)
    passwordField.send_keys("test12")
    submitButton.click()
```

Comment: This only works once. To get a more unique number, consider using a Unix Time Stamp http://stackoverflow.com/q/19801727/1106708

Comment: @kirbycope The question specifically asked for 100 accounts containing a prefix and a number and a domain, starting with number 1. That it only works once also depends on one's teardown methodology. That being said, it's generally a good idea to create unique email addresses since it's not very difficult.